# Using Case to match strings in sql server?

Tags: string, t-sql

I am trying to use `CASE` in a SQL Select statement that will allow me to get results where I can utilize the length of one string to produce the resutls of another string. These are for non-matched records from two data sets that share a common ID, but variant Data Source.

Case statement is below:

```
Select Column1, Column2, 
Case
When Column1 = 'Something" and Len(Column2) = '35' Then Column1 = "Something Else" and substring(Column2, 1, 35)
End as Column3
From  dbo.xxx
```

When I run it I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: That SQL doesn't make sense. Can you give some example data and show what you expected to happen?

Comment: This is the exact sql:                                                                                                                               Select Data_Source, CustomerID, 

CASE 
WHEN Data_Source = 'Test1' and Len(CustomerName) = '35'  
Then  Data_Source = 'Test2' and substring(CustomerName, 1, 35)
End  AS CustomerName
From dbo.xx

Comment: Data_Source CustomerID CustomerName Test xxx xxx PLC, (LONDON BR Test1 xxx xxx PLC(LONDON BR2)

Answer (score 10):

You need to have a value for each `WHEN`, and ought to have an `ELSE`:

```
Select Data_Source, CustomerID,
  CASE
    WHEN Data_Source = 'Test1' and Len(CustomerName) = 35 THEN 'First Value'
    WHEN Data_Source = 'Test2' THEN substring(CustomerName, 1, 35)
    ELSE 'Sorry, no match.'
    END AS CustomerName
  From dbo.xx
```

FYI: `Len()` doesn't return a string.

**EDIT:**
A SQL Server answer that addresses some of the comments might be:

```
declare @DataSource as Table ( Id Int Identity, CustomerName VarChar(64) )
declare @VariantDataSource as Table ( Id Int Identity, CostumerName VarChar(64) )
insert into @DataSource ( CustomerName ) values ( 'Alice B.' ), ( 'Bob C.' ), ( 'Charles D.' )
insert into @VariantDataSource ( CostumerName ) values ( 'Blush' ), ( 'Dye' ), ( 'Pancake Base' )

select *,
  -- Output the CostumerName padded or trimmed to the same length as CustomerName.  NULLs are not handled gracefully.
  Substring( CostumerName + Replicate( '.', Len( CustomerName ) ), 1, Len( CustomerName ) ) as Clustermere,
  -- Output the CostumerName padded or trimmed to the same length as CustomerName.  NULLs in CustomerName are explicitly handled.
  case
    when CustomerName is NULL then ''
    when Len( CustomerName ) > Len( CostumerName ) then Substring( CostumerName, 1, Len( CustomerName ) )
    else Substring( CostumerName + Replicate( '.', Len( CustomerName ) ), 1, Len( CustomerName ) )
    end as 'Crustymore'
  from @DataSource as DS inner join
    @VariantDataSource as VDS on VDS.Id = DS.Id
```

Comment: The `ELSE` part isn't mandatory in Transact-SQL CASE (if that was what you meant by *ought to*).

Comment: @AndriyM - It was a "best practices" suggestion.

Comment: I am not trying to use multiple WHEN in my statement, the intent is to manipulate data in records where the ID is similar but the Data Source (Column1) is variant so the length returned is the same. Of course adding ELSE is textbook, but not to be distracted from what I am trying to accomplish. Does anyone know why I would get that error when adding the '=' after my THEN? Or a solution that provides that allows me to use WHEN in this fashion. Any other suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: @user1368436 - As I tried to explain, the `THEN` provides a value to be returned as the value of the `CASE` expression.  You cannot have an assignment in the `THEN`.

Comment: Ok so then what would you suggest? I need to manipulate data in records where the ID is similar, but the Data Source (Column1) is variant so the same length is returned?

Comment: @user1368436 - I'm still not understanding the question.  If all you want is a fixed length string returned from a variable length column: `Substring( Coalesce( CustomerName, '' ) + Replicate( ' ', 35 ), 1, 35 ) as FixedCustomerName`

Comment: The question is very simple, I am trying to get records with the same ID from variant Data Sources to end up with the same length. One data source needs to be the driver of deterning the returned length. So if Data Source 'Test' record = 35, I want Data Source 'Test1' record also to return length 35.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select 
    Column1, 
    Column2, 
    Case 
      When Column1 = 'Something' and Len(Column2) = 35 
      Then 'Something Else' + substring(Column2, 1, 35) 
    End as Column3 
From dbo.xxx
```

Update your query on

1. use '+' for string concat
2. len() returns int, no need to use ''
3. remove "Column1 =" in the case when condition
4. replace "" with ''

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi Seanbun, thanks for your suggestion. I am not looking to concatenate any data here. Length is required to manipulate the data so that return values are the same length. I am looking to understand why the '=' is causing an error after my THEN or a suggestion how I can use WHEN to facilitate records with the same ID, variant Data Source to match the return length of a specific field.

Comment: Would 'Else' help? like below or could you declare a variable @Result to store your value and return at the end?

`Select 
    Column1, 
    Column2, 
    Case 
      When Column1 = 'Something' and Len(Column2) = 35 
      Then 'Something Else' + substring(Column2, 1, 35) 
   ELSE Column1
    End as Column3 
From dbo.xxx`